# Linq Returning Sum of 2 separate columns in same query

Tags: c#, linq

The code below brings through a row for each InvNo, along with the sum of "SCharge" :0

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
            group data by new
            {
                InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                Code = "1",
                InvType = "I",
                Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                SCharge = g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("SCharge"))
            };
```

Is there are way  of modifying this so that I get another set of rows below, this time doing a sum on the column "TCharge", or would I need to do a new query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since you want to show all of the rows twice, but with a slightly different projection the second time, we can start by saving a query for the groupings, and then performing two projections on those groups and combining them together.

```
var groupings = DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(data => new
                {
                    InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                    AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
                }).ToList();

var Values = groupings.Select(g => new
{
    Code = "1",
    InvType = "I",
    Account = g.Key.AccRef,
    InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
    Charge = g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("SCharge"))
})
.Concat(groupings.Select(g => new
{
    Code = "1",
    InvType = "I",
    Account = g.Key.AccRef,
    InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
    Charge = g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("SCharge"))
}));
```

Comment: Would that just add an additional column? What I want is an additional set of rows beneath the first set.

Comment: @MuhammadHani The comma at the end of the last line is not an error.  It is optional.  Adding the redundant comma is helpful in that it allows for much easier refactors; you can move or add items anywhere without special casing the last line.

Comment: @user1936588 Then just display the results of this query twice.  The first time show all but the last column, then iterate over the query again and skip the second to last.  If you do this, as opposed to writing two queries, you can avoid doing the grouping twice.

Comment: @Servy Would that involve having a second "select new"?

Comment: @user1936588 I've edited the code as it is sufficiently different.

Answer (score 0):

```
select new
     {
       Code = "1",
        InvType = "I",
        Account = g.Key.AccRef,
        InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
        SCharge = g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("SCharge")),
        TCharge = g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("TCharge"))
     };
```